# Facebook Like Box - how to make it show without logging in?

Tags: facebook, cross-browser, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

```
<%--Facebook Like Box--%>
   <div class="fb_iframe_widget">
        <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FRumour-Entertainments-Agency%2F63822323174&amp;width=260&amp;height=350&amp;show_faces=false&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;stream=true&amp;border_color&amp;header=true&amp;appId=123233914444256" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:260px; height:350px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
    </div>
```

It looks like facebook have been tinkering yet again! If you have a like box on your website it will only show up if you are logged in to facebook itself! What is the point though? What if a person does not have facebook? Is there a way to keep the like box on the website without having to log in to facebook to view the like box?

Am i not passing the facebook security checks if there any? Dont know whats changed from before so bit clueless at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is that you are referring to page which requires authentication.
I see you have in src attribute value of your URL as follows:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/FRumour-Entertainments-Agency/63822323174

and when you try it in browser separately it requires authentication

Comment: i came across this article which was quite helpful - yep i'll have to authenticate the page. http://www.profromgo.com/facebook-social-plugin-not-working/

Comment: Sorted it - removed the country from the settings and it works - double checking it now to be certain!